# How to tail multiple files without empty lines?

Tags: text-processing, tail

As I've noticed, a command such as
 `tail -n +5 a b`
prints its output in a format like this:

```
==>a<==

contents of a from line 5 to $EOF (including line 5)

==>b<==

contents of b from line 5 to $EOF (including line 5)
```

Is there a way (or perhaps another command) to print just the required contents from the specified line onwards? i.e.:

```
contents of a from line 5 to $EOF (including line 5)

contents of b from line 5 to $EOF (including line 5)
```

Comment: *from line 5* **including** the 5th line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the quiet option:

```
tail -q -n +5 a b
```

Answer (score 0):

The file information is written to stderr, the real data is written to stdout (as both should be). So even if there was no `-q` option you could throw it away with

```
tail ... 2>/dev/null
```

And if you redirect the `tail` output then the file information will not be redirected anyway:

```
tail ... >output
```